# NSMutablearray unexpected behavior: all objects equal to last object added

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsmutablearray

I am experiencing unexpected behavior when adding objects to an NSMutablearray.  Basically, i want to add an object at the end of the array.  All the objects in the array should be different.  But what I am seeing is that all the objects in the array equal to the last one that was inserted. I have included the relevant code:

```
   _trafficArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


    int _index = -1;
    int _currentIndex = 0;
    int _reportCount = 0;

TrafficReport *_report = [[TrafficReport alloc] init];


    while (true) {

        if (!xmlTextReaderRead(_reader)) break;

        switch (xmlTextReaderNodeType(_reader)) {     

            case XML_READER_TYPE_ELEMENT:


                temp = (char *)xmlTextReaderConstName(_reader);

                currentTagName = [NSString  stringWithCString:temp encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];

                if([currentTagName isEqualToString:@"Title"])
                {

                    _index++;

                    temp = (char *)xmlTextReaderConstName(_reader);

                    currentTagName = [NSString  stringWithCString:temp encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];


                    xmlTextReaderRead(_reader);

                    temp = (char*)xmlTextReaderConstValue(_reader);
                    currentTagValue = [NSString stringWithCString:temp 
                                                         encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];


                    _report.title = currentTagValue;

                    _reportCount++;


                }
                if ([currentTagName isEqualToString:@"Description"]) {

                    temp = (char *)xmlTextReaderConstName(_reader);

                    currentTagName = [NSString  stringWithCString:temp encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];

                    xmlTextReaderRead(_reader);

                    temp = (char*)xmlTextReaderConstValue(_reader);
                    currentTagValue = [NSString stringWithCString:temp 
                                                         encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

                    _report.description = currentTagValue;
                    _reportCount++;


                }

            if (_reportCount==2) {


                _reportCount = 0;

                NSLog(@"updated! with index = %d and title = %@\n\n", _index, _report.title);



                [_trafficArray insertObject:_report atIndex:_index];

                [_report release];

    TrafficReport *_report = [[TrafficReport alloc] init];


            }


            continue;

        default:continue;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an issue of scope. After you release `_report`, you declare a new `_report` object in the scope of the if statement. Even though it has the same name as the one you declared before the while loop, it refers to a different variable. Remove the declaration (`TrafficReport *`) before the assignment to assign a new value to your existing `_report` variable instead.

Comment: This is the right answer. I missed the allocation in the `if` statement, and @omz is completely right that you're declaring a new variable `_report` that (briefly) hides but doesn't replace the first one. Also, be sure that the last TrafficReport instance is properly released -- right now I think you're leaking an object.

Comment: Thank you, this did the trick.  Im relatively new to ios and objective c so this kind of issue can go over my head.